# Need help using PySimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

I need to organize my window in such a way that the image is placed on the right and does not affect the elements on the left.. I would really appreciate some help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR7G0.png)

Comment: Post your code in text code and image here directly if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways for it

- Align Frame to top

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Frame('myFrame', layout=[
        [sg.Text('Text 1')],
        [sg.Text('Text 2')],
        [sg.Button('A button')]], vertical_alignment='top'),
     sg.Image(filename='img.png'),
    ]
]

window = sg.Window('Hello', layout).read(close=True)
```

- Expand Frame with same height as Image

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Frame('myFrame', layout=[
        [sg.Text('Text 1')],
        [sg.Text('Text 2')],
        [sg.Button('A button')]], expand_y=True),
     sg.Image(filename='img.png'),
    ]
]

window = sg.Window('Hello', layout).read(close=True)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, your reply helped me.